# Why is my table size nearly 10 times bigger than expected from the avg_row_len?

Tags: oracle

In my Oracle database, I have a table with a size of 3.44 GB.  It's 1784486 rows, and 450146, which corresponds to a 8 kB block size, and an average of 4 rows per block, or 2 kB per row.  But the AVG_ROW_LEN is only 369 bytes.  What's causing the discrepency?

*More details:*

The PCT_FREE is only 10, so that shouldn't be responsible. Compression is currently turned off. The table layout is (column names generalized)

```
KEY            NUMBER(38)           NOT NULL,
DATE1          DATE                 NOT NULL,
DATE2          DATE                 NOT NULL,
POINT          NUMBER(4)            NOT NULL,
NAME           VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)   NOT NULL,
BLOB_SIZE      NUMBER(38)           NOT NULL,
BLOB_TYPE      VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
BLOB_FILTERS   VARCHAR2(64 BYTE)    NOT NULL,
BLOB_DATA      BLOB                 NOT NULL,
PRECOMPUTED    RAW(2000)    -- currently no more than ~200 bytes
                            -- (15 doubles, plus some headers)
```

Comment: How are you determining that the table has a size of 3.44 GB?  Are you looking at `ALL_SEGMENTS`?  How are you determining the number of rows?  By doing a `COUNT(*)`?  Or by looking at `NUM_ROWS` in `ALL_TABLES`?  How are you determining the number of blocks?  Are the statistics on this table accurate and up to date?  Have you looked at the output of `DBMS_SPACE.SPACE_USAGE` for this object?

Comment: I'm getting the numbers from TOAD.  (Also I forgot to add, this table was built up from converting a table in a previous format, so nothing should have ever been deleted, and there should be no unclaimed empty space.)

Comment: If I do the query myself against dba_segments, I get a size of 3695181824 bytes, which matches TOAD.  I just ran a `select count(*)` and surprisingly it does differ, 1787088 vs. TOADs 1784486.  Still not enough to explain the huge difference I'm seeing.

Comment: Let me also add, as tests of this redesign, there are also two copies of the table, with different partitions.  (The original is unpartitioned.)  All statistics across the tables agree to with a 2-3%.

Answer (score 4):

OK.  Let's start by figuring out where TOAD is getting the numbers you're looking at

What does

```
SELECT sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 size_in_gb,
       sum(blocks) size_in_blocks
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE owner = <<owner of table>>
   AND segment_name = <<name of table>>
```

return for the size of the table?

What does

```
SELECT num_rows, blocks, empty_blocks, avg_row_len, last_analyzed
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE owner = <<owner of table>>
   AND table_name = <<name of table>>
```

return for the statistics on the table?

What does

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM <<owner of table>>.<<name of table>>
```

return for the actual number of rows in the table?

What does

```
DECLARE
  l_unformatted_blocks number;
  l_unformatted_bytes number;
  l_fs1_blocks number;
  l_fs1_bytes number;
  l_fs2_blocks number;
  l_fs2_bytes number;
  l_fs3_blocks number;
  l_fs3_bytes number;
  l_fs4_blocks number;
  l_fs4_bytes number;
  l_full_blocks number;
  l_full_bytes number;
BEGIN
  dbms_space.space_usage (<<table owner>>, <<table name>>, 'TABLE',
                          l_unformatted_blocks, l_unformatted_bytes,
                          l_fs1_blocks, l_fs1_bytes, l_fs2_blocks, l_fs2_bytes,
                          l_fs3_blocks, l_fs3_bytes, l_fs4_blocks, l_fs4_bytes,
                          l_full_blocks, l_full_bytes);
  dbms_output.put_line('Unformatted Blocks = '||l_unformatted_blocks);
  dbms_output.put_line('FS1 Blocks = '||l_fs1_blocks);
  dbms_output.put_line('FS2 Blocks = '||l_fs2_blocks);
  dbms_output.put_line('FS3 Blocks = '||l_fs3_blocks);
  dbms_output.put_line('FS4 Blocks = '||l_fs4_blocks);
  dbms_output.put_line('Full Blocks = '||l_full_blocks);
END;
```

show for how the blocks in the table are being utilized?

Were the rows updated after January 14th at 14:02:29?  In particular, is it possible that a number of rows were inserted that were relatively small but then subsequently were updated to be much larger in size?  Does anything change if you re-gather statistics on the table

```
BEGIN
  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( ownname          => <<owner of table>>,
                                 tabname          => <<name of table>>,
                                 estimate_percent => null,
                                 granularity      => 'ALL' );
END;
```

Comment: I get (3.44140625, 451072) for the size_in_gb and size_in_blocks.  For the second query I get (1784486, 450146, 0, 369, 2012-Jan-14 14:02:29)).  (The table was created roughly then, and nothing has been added since the initial creation.)  And the count, as I stated above, is 1787088.

Comment: I'm just guessing about the 8kB block size.  I'm not an admin, and I forgot where I found it, but it seems to be the usual setting, and it does match the size divided by the number of blocks.

Comment: @AFoglia - OK.  Can you also run the `DBMS_SPACE` call I just posted and post the results?

Comment: The results are `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`. :-)  I'll ask one of the DB admins to run it, but it might take a while to get an answer.

Comment: I just got the results from the admins.  Here's the numbers:
Unformatted Blocks = 1280, 
FS1 Blocks = 1, 
FS2 Blocks = 0, 
FS3 Blocks = 0, 
FS4 Blocks = 410, 
Full Blocks = 448455,

Comment: @AFoglia - OK.  Does the `AVG_ROW_LEN` change if you gather statistics on the table again?

Comment: "In particular, is it possible that a number of rows were inserted that were relatively small but then subsequently were updated to be much larger in size?"  No.  This table was built from converting another table's data to a new format.  Even if I did restart the conversion job after it started, the table would have been cleared as the first thing, and there are two additional partitioned copies made from this table that show similar discrepencies (AVG_ROW_LEN 369 bytes, Size/num_rows ~2100 bytes).  (I'll ask the admins to generate the stats, but I doubt that'll do anything.)